# Can this formula be used in an ARRAYFORMULA in Google Sheets?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I have a formula that I've been trying to convert to an ARRAYFORMULA but I've been unsuccessful. As the formula is (below) it works just fine but when I convert to an ARRAYFORMULA it shows blank (because I asked the formula to show " " if none of the conditions are met.

Here's the non-array formula:

```
    =IFERROR(IF(AND(D5="SAN BERNARDINO",K5>1,K5<1001),VLOOKUP(D5,ApprovalKey,2,FALSE),
IF(AND(D5="SAN BERNARDINO",K5>1002,K5<5001),VLOOKUP(D5,ApprovalKey,3,FALSE),
IF(AND(D5="SAN BERNARDINO",K5>5002,K5<10001),VLOOKUP(D5,ApprovalKey,4,FALSE),
IF(AND(D5="SAN BERNARDINO",K5>10002),VLOOKUP(D5,ApprovalKey,5,FALSE),
IF(AND(D5="ATLANTA",K5>1,K5<1001),VLOOKUP(D5,ApprovalKey,2,FALSE),
IF(AND(D5="ATLANTA",K5>1002,K5<5001),VLOOKUP(D5,ApprovalKey,3,FALSE),
IF(AND(D5="ATLANTA",K5>5002,K5<10001),VLOOKUP(D5,ApprovalKey,4,FALSE),
IF(AND(D5="ATLANTA",K5>10002),VLOOKUP(D5,ApprovalKey,5,FALSE),
IF(AND(D5="BEDFORD PARK",K5>1,K5<1001),VLOOKUP(D5,ApprovalKey,2,FALSE),
IF(AND(D5="BEDFORD PARK",K5>1002,K5<5001),VLOOKUP(D5,ApprovalKey,3,FALSE),
IF(AND(D5="BEDFORD PARK",K5>5002,K5<10001),VLOOKUP(D5,ApprovalKey,4,FALSE),
IF(AND(D5="BEDFORD PARK",K5>10002),VLOOKUP(D5,ApprovalKey,5,FALSE),"")))))))))))))
```

and here's the array I attempted:

```
    =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(AND(D2:D="SAN BERNARDINO",K2:K>1,K2:K<1001),VLOOKUP(D2:D,ApprovalKey,2,FALSE),IF(AND(D2:D="SAN BERNARDINO",K2:K>1002,K2:K<5001),VLOOKUP(D2:D,ApprovalKey,3,FALSE),
IF(AND(D2:D="SAN BERNARDINO",K2:K>5002,K2:K<10001),VLOOKUP(D2:D,ApprovalKey,4,FALSE),
IF(AND(D2:D="SAN BERNARDINO",K2:K>10002),VLOOKUP(D2:D,ApprovalKey,5,FALSE),
IF(AND(D2:D="ATLANTA",K2:K>1,K2:K<1001),VLOOKUP(D2:D,ApprovalKey,2,FALSE),
IF(AND(D2:D="ATLANTA",K2:K>1002,K2:K<5001),VLOOKUP(D2:D,ApprovalKey,3,FALSE),
IF(AND(D2:D="ATLANTA",K2:K>5002,K2:K<10001),VLOOKUP(D2:D,ApprovalKey,4,FALSE),
IF(AND(D2:D="ATLANTA",K2:K>10002),VLOOKUP(D2:D,ApprovalKey,5,FALSE),
IF(AND(D2:D="BEDFORD PARK",K2:K>1,K2:K<1001),VLOOKUP(D2:D,ApprovalKey,2,FALSE),
IF(AND(D2:D="BEDFORD PARK",K2:K>1002,K2:K<5001),VLOOKUP(D2:D,ApprovalKey,3,FALSE),
IF(AND(D2:D="BEDFORD PARK",K2:K>5002,K2:K<10001),VLOOKUP(D2:D,ApprovalKey,4,FALSE),
IF(AND(D2:D="BEDFORD PARK",K2:K>10002),VLOOKUP(D2:D,ApprovalKey,5,FALSE),"")))))))))))))
```

Am I just not allowed to use an arrayformula in this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sure, try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(
 IF((D5:D="SAN BERNARDINO")*(K5:K>1)   *(K5:K<1001), VLOOKUP(D5:D,ApprovalKey,2,0),
 IF((D5:D="SAN BERNARDINO")*(K5:K>1002)*(K5:K<5001), VLOOKUP(D5:D,ApprovalKey,3,0),
 IF((D5:D="SAN BERNARDINO")*(K5:K>5002)*(K5:K<10001),VLOOKUP(D5:D,ApprovalKey,4,0),
 IF((D5:D="SAN BERNARDINO")*(K5:K>10002),            VLOOKUP(D5:D,ApprovalKey,5,0),
 IF((D5:D="ATLANTA")       *(K5:K>1)   *(K5:K<1001), VLOOKUP(D5:D,ApprovalKey,2,0),
 IF((D5:D="ATLANTA")       *(K5:K>1002)*(K5:K<5001), VLOOKUP(D5:D,ApprovalKey,3,0),
 IF((D5:D="ATLANTA")       *(K5:K>5002)*(K5:K<10001),VLOOKUP(D5:D,ApprovalKey,4,0),
 IF((D5:D="ATLANTA")       *(K5:K>10002),            VLOOKUP(D5:D,ApprovalKey,5,0),
 IF((D5:D="BEDFORD PARK")  *(K5:K>1)   *(K5:K<1001), VLOOKUP(D5:D,ApprovalKey,2,0),
 IF((D5:D="BEDFORD PARK")  *(K5:K>1002)*(K5:K<5001), VLOOKUP(D5:D,ApprovalKey,3,0),
 IF((D5:D="BEDFORD PARK")  *(K5:K>5002)*(K5:K<10001),VLOOKUP(D5:D,ApprovalKey,4,0),
 IF((D5:D="BEDFORD PARK")  *(K5:K>10002),            VLOOKUP(D5:D,ApprovalKey,5,0),
 ))))))))))))))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks for commenting so quickly! The formula is supposed to identify the location and the cost parameters and, using that, search the key for the appropriate email address to return. The formula you provided gives me a blank return (nothing in the cell) rather than returning the email address. Here's a copy of the worksheet for reference https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qtMI0EiCKU0iyUMfhSOgCbwuQsohCSIXxQNFW9mZ4lM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: this formula is made for row 5. you put it in row 2 thats why you are getting blank cell. check your sheet where I fixed it

Comment: Oh my goodness how did I miss that. Yep you were right, this works perfectly! Thanks!